# How to conquer a stone age planet as devouring swarm?

Tags: stellaris

I am playing as devouring swarm and found a nice Gaia planet in my borders, which is inhabited by some stone age primitives. So I invaded the planet with my armies in order to colonize it and get a nice stone age snack.

But as it turns out this is not how it works. After the invasion the planet has an "Occupied" marker, but I have no control over the planet and I also can not eat the primitives. My Native Interference policy is set to "unrestricted".

Here is how it looks like:
[image]

Is there anything else I can do get full control over this planet right away or do I maybe need to wait until they advance to the bronze age?

Comment: AFAIK, neither Devouring Swarms nor stone-age primitives are intended to act differently in this case, so this may be a bug, related to this note from the [2.2.5 change log](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/stellaris-dev-diary-141-exploring-the-future.1155962/): " * Ensured capital buildings can convert to the correct type when a planet of primitives/machines/hive minds is taken over by another empire type". If this is that bug, the fix should be going live sometime next week.

Comment: It may be a bug, however I've seen this particular bug and it looks different. With the bug you get full control and only the capital building is not converted. But here I get no control over the planet what-so-ever.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug of the current version of the game. It will happen with any primitive and any hive mind. If you're bothered by their presence, blow them up with the colossus)

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, its not possible to devour primitives with a devouring swarm in the current version of the game (2.2.4). I also tried with more advanced primitives, but got the same result.

The only option to colonize such a planet at the moment is to conduct orbital bombardment it until all primitive pops are dead. After that you get the colonize option.